# CSS element not floating when float property specified

Tags: html, css

I am trying to float a navbar element so it can be taken outside of its float and displayed on top of the second element which is a div. unfortunately, i figured that the navbar didn't float when the css display property of the div below the navbar is set to flex. is there anyway to get around this problem while keeping the div as a flex? **without wrapping the both element inside a div.** the goal is to get the same background for both element navbar and div without wrapping them inside one div.

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Act Now!</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">FAQ</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="hero">
</div>


.nav{ 
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  width:100%;
  float:left;
}

.nav li {
  background:#000;
  list-style: none;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 0 40px;
  margin:0px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 16px rgba(121, 121, 121, 0.25);
  border-radius: 60px;
}

.nav li:hover {
  background: red;
  transition: background .3s;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hero{
  background:#999;
  height:100px;
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/nidhalmejai/pen/LYejGbY the problem is the navbar is not floating if the div below it has a display flex.

Comment: Please, add you code.

Comment: I think there may be a misunderstanding of what float actually means in CSS. Could you perhaps give an image (a sketch would be fine) of what you want. Are you trying to get the hero under the navbar?

Comment: @AHaworth yes exactly

Comment: Is there a reason that the nav bar isn't a child of the hero?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the nav _is_ floating. But making the div `display:flex` changes the way that the div interacts with the float. The theoretically purest way to get what you want is to give the nav a right margin of `-100%`, but giving it zero height might also work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your question is quite unclear, what I understand is that you want the background on "hero" to be the background for your "nav".

I give you 2 solutions -

1. Remove "hero". Just use "nav" and add the background styles to it (along with appropriate padding).

   ```
   .nav { 
       display:flex;
       justify-content:center;
       width:100%;
       background:#999;
       padding: 20px 0; // padding is just to make this look better
   }
   // Instead of padding, you could set a height to this flex and force it's children
   // to be vertically aligned to the center using vertical-align: middle on .nav AND
   // margin: 20px; on .nav li instead of the current margin: 0 20px;
   ```
2. Keep the "hero" element as it is. Use positioning on "nav" to achieve this effect (you mentioned not wanting to wrap the tags in one common div - that means position absolute, would not work for you). But position: fixed OR position: sticky **might**

   ```
   .nav { 
       display:flex;
       justify-content:center;
       width:100%;
       position: fixed;
       padding: 20px 0; // padding is just to make this look better
   }
   ```

Comment: position: absolute worked and now the navbar is above the hero. thank you

Answer (score 0):

give your `*` element

```
position:relitive;
```

add these styles to `.hero`

```
 position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
```

https://codepen.io/abdurrahmanseyidoglu/pen/abEyNBm

Comment: sorry! the other divs below that hero will collapse to top

Comment: @AmineBinOthman Could you provide an image of what you want to achieve exactly?